# Set the "Location" value in Network pref pane without using private APIs

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, location, mac-app-store

Is there a way to programmatically set the "Location" value in the Network preference pane without using private APIs?

I need to do this in a way that will be accepted by the Mac App Store.

Comment: What purpose would this serve? I don't think users would be too happy if all the sudden their location changed without them knowing.

Comment: A customer wants that feature. Go figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there's no library function that will reliably achieve this, but you could execute the `networksetup` tool:

```
/usr/sbin/networksetup -switchtolocation $LOCATION
```

Alas, I’m not sure if this is allowed for MAS apps. The only way to know for sure is as always just trying.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there **are** public & available API's that can do what you're looking for.

Take a look at the [System Configuration framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/SCNetworkConfiguration/Reference/reference.html).  The actual call that I use in my own code that sets a new location (with my users being fully aware that it's happening) is `SCNetworkSetSetCurrent`.

That said, there's two reasons why you can't do this in your own code:

number 1) as @gcbrueckmann said (and +1 for him for saying so), doing this in a sandboxed app for sale in the Mac App Store is sure to be a no no.

number 2) if you're going to be messing with System Configuration settings that modify system level settings, you need to do it from a privileged (i.e. running as admin or root) tool or app.

Comment: In my experience, `SCNetworkSetSetCurrent()` does not work as expected (requires root privileges, as you've pointed out). The `networksetup` tool method, however, does not. (It is documented to require admin rights, though.)

Answer (score 0):

scselect will work and does not require admin privileges.

```
scselect $LOCATION
```

But you may not be able to use that from a sandbox.

You can also change it via AppleScript, but again, from a sandbox may be problematic.